# Getting properties of random points in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, image, sampling, samplepoints

I want to have random points across Peru and their properties (the band values of IMAGE) for statistical analysis in GEE. I found two options which are sampling and random points. I have tried the following lines:

```
var samplevalues= IMAGE.sample({ region: peru.geometry(),numPixels: 10000, geometries: true});
var randompoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(peru.geometry(), 1000).set('samplenumber');
```

None of them gave me the desired output. *samplevalues* keeps the bands in IMAGE and shows them as properties of each sample points, but the points are within IMAGE borders. Whereas, *randompoints* gives points without properties across Peru.

How can I get random points over Peru, and IMAGE bands as their properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `sampleRegions` to add the image bands as properties to the collection of random points.

```js
var randompoints = ee.FeatureCollection.randomPoints(peru.geometry(), 1000);
var samples = IMAGE.sampleRegions({
  collection: randompoints,
  geometries: true,
});
print(samples);
```

`sampleRegions` is very similar to `sample`, but it chooses points from within the given regions (so if the regions are themselves points, you get those points as results).